# Solving C warning - dereferencing a null pointer

Tags: c, pointers, null, dereference

This is the bug report from facebook infer.

```
error: NULL_DEREFERENCE
  pointer `stack` last assigned on line 24 could be null and is dereferenced at line 25, column 5.
  22. struct string_stack* create_String_Stack(unsigned capacity)
  23.   {
  24.       struct char_stack* stack = calloc(1,sizeof(struct char_stack));
  25. >     stack-> capacity = capacity;
  26.       stack->top = -1;
  27.       stack->array = (char*)malloc(stack->capacity * sizeof(char));
```

```
struct char_stack
{
    int top;
    unsigned capacity;
    char* array;
};
```

How can get rid of this warning?

Comment: Check the result of calloc? `if(stack == NULL) { /* handle error & terminate */ }`.

Comment: The warning is 100% correct. `calloc` could return `NULL` and you don't check this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is at `struct char_stack* stack = calloc(1,sizeof(struct char_stack));`. If you just simply say `struct char_stack* stack= malloc(sizeof(struct char_stack);` as you want only 1 item to save space and then I believe that it probably solve it. If it does not then I would suggest checking if you correctly pronounce sizeof(struct char_stack).In the end, you always must check `if (stack==NULL)`  because the program might not find a space to allocate space for the pointer. Also, I would recommend using  `typedef struct char_stack Char_stack;` so you don't need to write all the time the `struct char_stack`  but only  `Char_stack`. I hope that this will help you to find the problem.

Comment: I still got this error when using malloc. But there will be too many branches in the code if a check for null each time. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You need to check only once per allocation. If you don't want to use 'if' then use try {..}catch{..} block

Comment: @gobinda To use `try {...} catch {...}` the OP would need to use a different programming language.

Comment: Using a diffferent size for memory allocation cannot solve the problem. `malloc` can still return `NULL` which must be checked.